# Proving minimum of distances exists

Tags: optimization

My first stackexchange post! I'm ready to be flamed haha. ;)

My problem: For some n points, prove that there exists a point p that minimizes the sum of the distances between p and each of the n points.

At first, I thought this would be easy to prove, as it's pretty intuitive. It's easy to see there's no maximum for the distance, so how do I prove that there must be some minimum?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let $D$ be a disk containing all the points $\{M_i\}$ and $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}, f(P) = \sum_i |PM_i|$. Then $f$ is continuous and $D$ is compact, therefore the image of $f$ is compact, which means bounded.

Comment: I know it should be intuitive, but what says P can't be outside disk D?

Comment: @ekim Take the disk big enough

Comment: Oh is that what you meant by f:D→R+?

Comment: argh im still confused where to go from here...

Comment: Is the next step to take the fact that f is continuous and use the extreme value theorem on this compact image of f to determine that a minimum S(P)  exists?

Comment: @ekim Yes .....